# Sometimes ADFS exception: ID1032 "At least one 'audienceUri' must be specified..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif, adfs

I have a project which uses ADFS authentication in some cases. The configuration is read from a database and the URLs are different from customer to customer, so there are many configuration options which I can't hard-code in my `Web.config`.

The problem is that I get the following error:

> ID1032: At least one 'audienceUri' must be specified in the SamlSecurityTokenRequirement when the AudienceUriMode is set to 'Always' or 'BearerKeyOnly'

But I don't get it always, and I can't reproduce it. This is pretty annoying since I can't really debug it as long as I can't reproduce it. And I'm not sure whether I did everything correct. Maybe some ADFS expert can have a look at it.

(Trusts between my relying parties and their corresponding ADFS servers have been established, of course.)

Here is my code (only interesting parts of it), please ask if anything is missing or unclear.

Some snippets from my `Web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </modules>
  <!-- ... -->
</system.webServer>
```

```xml
<microsoft.identityModel>
  <service>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler" />
      <add type="MyProject.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler" />
    </securityTokenHandlers>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false"
                    issuer="https://fail/IssuerEndpoint"
                    realm="https://fail/FederationResult"
                    homeRealm="https://fail"
                    requireHttps="true" />
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
```

Those *fail* values will be overridden per request (see my `Login()` method below), but I have to specify something in my `Web.config`, so I chose to specify a valid URI at least. The default `SessionSecurityTokenHandler` had to be replaced because my service runs on multiple machines with DNS Round-Robin (sharing the same machine key).

Then I have a class I called `AdfsTrustFilter` which implements `IAuthorizationFilter`. I know it's bit of overhead, but due to the project structure, this filter is used as a global filter on every request (order is the least value in the whole project). In the `OnAuthorization` method, I complete the configuration as follows:

```c#
public sealed class AdfsTrustFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        // ...

        var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;

        fam.ServiceConfiguration = new ServiceConfiguration
        {
            AudienceRestriction = new AudienceRestriction(AudienceUriMode.Always),
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust,
            // MyIssuerNameRegistry checks whether a fingerprint is known and some other stuff
            IssuerNameRegistry = new MyIssuerNameRegistry()
        };

        // config.OwnPath contains something like "https://my.app.com/AppRoot/"
        fam.ServiceConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri(config.OwnPath));
    }
}
```

This is the code that starts the authentication:

```c#
public ActionResult Login()
{
    // ...

    // again something like "https://my.app.com/AppRoot/"
    string baseUrl = Config.OwnPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";

    // adfs endpoint for this customer: i.e. "https://identity.provider.net/adfs/ls/"
    string endpoint = Config.AdfsConfig.IdentityProvider.Endpoint;

    // the code behind FederationResult is shown below
    var signIn = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri(endpoint), baseUrl + "/Adfs/FederationResult")
                        {
                            Context = baseUrl
                        };

    var url = signIn.WriteQueryString();

    return Redirect(url);
}
```

And finally the `FederationResult` callback:

```c#
public ActionResult FederationResult()
{
    WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
    HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (fam.CanReadSignInResponse(request, true))
    {
        var id = (IClaimsIdentity) User.Identity;

        // do something
    }

    // ...
}
```

P.S.: The ADFS server was recently upgraded from 2008 R2 to 2012, but this didn't change anything. ADFS version was always 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception says that you need the audienceUri, I would start by adding one under

```
 <microsoft.IdentityModel>
    <service>
       <audienceUris>
          <add value="https://yourdomain/theaudienceuri" />
```

The audienceUri is the Uri adfs returns to your application. You can override the engine to accept arbitrary return results which doesn't change the fact that indeed you need at least one uri in the config.

Comment: A good idea (and I'll try it), but why does it work _without_ a configured audience URI most of the time? At this time I set the audience URI solely by code and only get this exception once in a while.

Comment: Great question, sounds like the authorizaiton filter sometimes doesn't work? Without deeper debugging, I can't think of an obvious reason.